insertion in Oracle BLOB a binary field, but shows it as string
I am working with NiFi reading from a kafka's topic and then I insert it into a ORACLE.
My topic have 1 field that is binary, and when I read that field in ORACLE appear as binary.
Perfect. I am working with NiFi 1.12.1
I am repeating the same flow in NiFi 1.15.3 inserting the same same into the same table, but with NiFi 1.15.3 and the field appear as string.
Someone have any idea how to work with this issue ?
I am using the same odbc driver in both NiFi and the java version are:
NiFi 1.12.1 -> openjdk 1.8.0_232
NiFi 1.15.3 -> openjdk 1.8.0_322
Thanks
